# Silverstripe HTML Block "Form Action"

Tags: php, silverstripe

Been searching around trying to find away to achieve a "HTMLBlock":

```
/**
 * @see \HTMLBlock
 */
$fields = array(
    TextField::create('myTextfield', 'My Text Field Label'),
    HTMLBlock::create('<div>Hey I put a HTML block between real fields'),
    TextField::create('myTextfield2', 'My Second Text Field Label')
)
```

Anyone able to provide a pointer on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`LiteralField`](//api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-LiteralField.html) to insert html into a form like so:

```
$fields = array(
    TextField::create('myTextfield', 'My Text Field Label'),
    LiteralField::create('myLiteralField1', '<b>some bold text</b> and <a href="http://silverstripe.com">a link</a>'),
    TextField::create('myTextfield2', 'My Second Text Field Label')
);
```